# Is there a way to see the date/time I bookmarked a question?

Tags: support, data-explorer, bookmarks, time

Is there a way to see the date/time I bookmarked a question? I looked at [How do question bookmarks work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-question-bookmarks-work), but my question was not addressed. I know that on my profile page I can go to the “Votes” tab and find the date on which I voted on a question/answer, but I don’t think I can do this for my bookmarks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not in the web user interface, but you can write a [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/introducing-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-aka-sede) query to display the bookmark creation date.

Here's [one I wrote earlier](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1476106/question-bookmark-dates)

Just enter the question id ([it's the number in the question URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36714/logic-behind-stackoverflow-question-ids)) and make sure you've chosen the right site and it will show you who bookmarked a question and when they did it.

The SEDE database is only updated once a week so if you bookmarked a question very recently you might have to rely on your memory for a few days.

Comment: Whatever post I put, all the bookmarks have a creation date of ```yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00```. Although it's *possible*, I doubt every bookmark was added at exactly midnight. Could this be because the database is updated at midnight?

Comment: I think that is because a bookmark is considered a vote, and votes are somewhat obfuscated to make it impossible to link up and downvotes to an individual user. @JamesA

Comment: @JamesA What Luuklag said is correct: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/933/why-is-vote-time-missing-in-the-se-data-dump-and-sede and related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248526/expose-vote-time-data-for-accepts-bounty-starts-awards-and-edit-approvals-in-t